# MongoDB query: limit the number of returned documents by each value mapped $in an array

Tags: mongodb

## 1

```
db.files.find( { extenstion: pdf } ).limit(5)
db.files.find( { extenstion: docx } ).limit(5)
db.files.find( { extenstion: png } ).limit(5)
```

## 2

```
db.files.find( { extenstion: { $in: [pdf, docx, png] } } ).limit(5)
```

I know both 1 and 2 are available, but if I want 5 documents for each values mapped $in an array, is there something like:

```
db.files.find( { extenstion: { $in: [pdf, docx, png] } } ).limitForEach(5)
// Expected 15 documents are returned.
```

Then we are able to do only 1 query rather than 3.

Thank you.

Comment: See JIRA Issue [SERVER-9377](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9377). Right now this is not practical, and the best approach is to run the "three" queries in parallel and concatenate the results.